# Scope, Namespace, and Files Architecture

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a Visual Studio Project where the App can be subdivided into 3 sections.
Each section behaves independently from the others. Each section will include its own set of .vb files, which will include Modules (as `static` classes), Classes, and Variables ideally "global" to the level of the section.

What would be best practice to organise my .vb files?

Architecturally speaking, a Main `Module` (File = 'Main.vb') will call, on demand, one of the 3 sections by calling a section `Module` (for example SectionA in 'SectionA.vb'). Then this SectionA `Module` will call other Modules or Classes included in other .vb files, which will be stored into separate folders.

We would have something like:

1. Main.vb (contains Main `Module`)
2. SectionA.vb (contains SectionA `Module`)
3. SectionB.vb (contains SectionB `Module`)
4. SectionC.vb (contains SectionC `Module`)
5. SectionA/ClassA1.vb (contains ClassA1 `Class`)
6. SectionA/ModuleA2.vb (contains other things)
7. SectionB/ClassB1.vb (contains things)
8. etc.

How do I make sure anything included in folder 'SectionA' can only be accessed by the SectionA `Module`? This would be equivalent to having all the blocks of the 'SectionA' folder encapsulated inside the SectionA `Module` and set to `Private`. However, I do like the flexibility of having the source code across several files (more or less one class per file).

So far, I am using `Namespace` to organise things, but this does not fix the scope problem: any `Public Sub` of the 'SectionA' folder can be accessed from any project file. I also tried to set the Module (Modules, Classes) declaration to `Private` within the Namespace, but it looks like this is forbidden

See intents below:

**FILE Main.vb**

```
Module MainModule
    Sub Main()
        Select Case UserChoice
            Case ChoseA1
                Call SectionA.DoThings()
            Case ChoseA2
                Call SectionA.DoOtherThings()
            Case ChoseB
                Call SectionB
            Case ChoseC
                Call SectionC
        End Select
    End Sub
End Module
```

**FILE SectionA.vb**

```
Namespace SectionA
    Module Main
        Private MySectionPrivateVariable
        Sub DoThings()
            Dim OneClass As New ClassA1
            Call DoMoreThings()
        End Sub
        Sub DoOtherThings()
            '...
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

**Helper FILES inside SectionA folder**

```
Namespace SectionA
    Module SectionA1
        Private MyModulePrivateVariable
        Sub DoMoreThings()
            '...
            'Problem: Cannot access SectionA.MySectionPrivateVariable
        End Sub
    End Module

    Public Class ClassA1
        '...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**FILE SectionB.vb**

```
Namespace SectionB
    Module Main
        Private MySectionPrivateVariable
        Sub DoManyThings()
            '...
            'Problem: Can access SectionA.ClassA1
            'Problem: Can access SectionA.DoMoreThings()
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to split your application into multiple projects (one for each of your "sections").  Make each of them a class library project with it's own namespace (I would recommend naming the project the same thing as the namespace), and then have the main project reference all the class library projects via project references (as opposed to DLL file references).  Once they are in their own projects, you can then control the accessibility by setting things to `Friend`.

Alternatively, you could nest all of the helper types within the module, then you can set the accessibility to `Private`, but that could get messy fast:

```
Namespace SectionA
    Module Main
        Sub DoThings()
            Dim OneClass As New ClassA1
            ' ...
        End Sub

        Private Class ClassA1
            ' ...
        End Class
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: Totally agreed on the Alternative option getting messy quickly, which is why I was looking for another way. Your suggestion on multiple projects sounds promising; never used multiple projects before so I'll give it a try and get back to you after a few tests. Thanks!

Comment: I ran a few tests. Am I right in concluding that a DLL cannot be part of a Solution? So I would need to create my Solution with on Project (the "startup" Project), and then add references to the various DLLs? Which also mens I woul need to compile the DLLs first?+

Comment: No. That is not correct. You certainly _can_ do it that way, but you don’t need to, nor would I advise it. You need to add the class library projects to the same solution as your main project (the start up project). Then you can reference those libraries via references to the projects (rather than references to precompiled dll files). When you build the solution, visual studio will automatically build all the dependency projects first, and then copy the output dll files into the main project’s output folder.

Comment: Slowly getting there.. I now managed to have Class Libraries in the same solution as my Windows Form (for others reading, you need to go to File/Add/New Project, instead of File/New Project). So now I have my two projects. I did Project/Add Reference... on my Windows Form and ticked my Class Library project in Projects/Solution. The Project library includes a public class, yet I cannot declare it from the Windows Form. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds good so far.  As long as it references the project, and the class in that project is public, then it should work.  The only remaining issue would be the namespace.  If the class is in a different namespace, you obviously need to fully qualify the class name with the namespace or import the namespace at the top of the file.

Comment: By the way if you know any good tutorial on Visual Studio (on the solution, files, configuration manager, etc) I would love if you coul share a linkj. So far I am learning with this kind of [outdated tutorial](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Mastering+visual+studio+.net) for VS 20**03**

Comment: Spot on! I was not using the correct `Namespace`. And about this, you said I should have the project name identical to the namespace. From what I just saw this seems to be the default behaviour. What if I wanted to do it differently? (I won't do it but I want to fully understand VS behaviour). Do I just manage this from within the code with the odd `Namespace` keyword or is there a Project/File property to setup somewhere?

Comment: Correct, it defaults the namespace to whatever you called the project.  If you go to `My Project` > `Application`, there's a `Root namespace` setting which sets the top level namespace for all the code in the project (unless you manually override it with the `Global` keyword, e.g. `Namespace Global.MyManuallyOverridenTopLevelNamespace`).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you once again for your help, and if you know any tutorial other than the one I mentionned I'll take it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a good one.  I did a quick search and nothing great was coming up for me either.

Comment: For anyone reading, there is also this source of info, from 2008: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/wbzbtw81(v%3dvs.90)

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) seems to be the closest equivalent to the newest version of that document.